# python как удалить определенные файлы в папке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть папка с кучей файлов, и при копировании появились дубликаты, разница только в весе этих файлов. Оригинал весит чуть больше, примерно на 40%. Как можно удалить файлы которые ниже определенного веса в папке?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример как получить размер файла:

```
>>> import os
>>> b = os.path.getsize("/path/isa_005.mp3")
>>> b
2071611
```

А вот пример, как удалить файл...

```
>>> import os
>>> os.remove("/tmp/<file_name>.txt")
```

Comment: здесь уместнее использовать библиотеку pathlib

Comment: Аргументируйте плз. А лучше дайте свой ответ в виде кода.

Comment: Суть в экономии памяти, вы используете две библиотеки os, os.path, в библиотеке pathlib реализованы обе функции. Так же ооп, снизит вероятность ошибок. На мой взгляд...

Comment: Ну раз все так хорошо, давайте код плз... )

Comment: Виноват, не понимаю иронии... ```import pathlib p=pathlib.Path('file'); p.stat()['st_size']; p.unlink();``` напрягает то, что получение размера файла это функция, а не переменная? но при вызове функции мы гарантировано получим не устаревшую инфу. (сбрасывая кэш). Хотя... когда-то слышал что pathlib исспользует модуль os, но это не точно... потом перечитаю доки